# How to solve a system of linear inequalities which satisfies most of the given constraints?

Tags: math, matrix, machine-learning, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I need to find a solution to a system of linear inequalities of the form

```
a11*x1 + a12*x2 +... a1i*xi >= b1

a21*x1 + a22*x2 +... a2i*xi >= b2
```

and so on and in case no solution exists, then return a solution `x` which satisfies most of the constraints. If multiple values satisfy give any.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Formulating this as an optimization problem is probably not the big issue here. But I guess it's not possible to formulate this as a problem with smooth constraints. So the real problem is probably that problems of this kind are very hard to optimize.

Comment: There exists an exponential solution , but that is inefficient . Can it be done in polynomial time ?

Comment: If I had to guess I would say that this problem is equal to optimizing a L0 norm, and this is proven to be np-hard. But that's just my intuition, I cannot say for sure.

Comment: You could add a non-negative slack variable to every inequality and then minimize the sum of all slack variables. If your optimal objective function value then is 0 you have found a feasible solution for your ```x``` variables. If not, then at least some of your slacks may be 0, though this won't yield a solution that satisfies *most constraints*, as you have required.

Comment: What size of problem are we talking about? how many x's and how many constraints? There are several options you might want to try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an objective function also, you can solve them in Excel Solver. But that wont be suitable for big equations. For bigger equations, you can use a Java Library (LpSolve). And as mentioned above, you can add slack variables in every equation with high penalty cost in the objective function.